# Does anybody know an Implementation of yarowsky's algorithm?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, word-sense-disambiguation

I want to find collocation in huge text using yarowsky's algorithm.
I have read about this algorithm in these links:

[wikipedia and Yarowsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarowsky_algorithm)

[google book and yarowsky](http://books.google.com/books?id=cwNxbeSlIXoC&pg=PA361&dq=yarowsky%20%2b%20collocation&hl=en&ei=kK8VTt7lEort0gGYlNVf&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=yarowsky%20%2b%20collocation&f=false)
I wanted to know if there is an implementation of the yarowsky's algorithm`? 
please help me find some code for this algorithm.
thanks

Comment: If you are nice, you could try asking Dr. Yarowsky: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~yarowsky/home.html

Comment: Just keep in mind he may get emails like this a lot, so be nice to the man and expect that it may take him awhile to get back to you. Also, if you do get an answer you may want to post it here on SO in case anyone else is looking for code as well.

Answer (score 4):

It appears a Master's student named Max Whitney has code which implements an updated version of Yarowsky's algorithm:

> Bootstrapping a classifier from a small set of seed rules can be viewed as the propagation of labels between examples via features shared between them. This paper introduces a novel variant of the Yarowsky algorithm based on this view. It is a bootstrapping learning method which uses a graph propagation algorithm with a well defined objective function. The experimental results show that our proposed bootstrapping algorithm achieves state of the art performance or better on several different natural language data sets.

Description from: http://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~mwhitney/personal/#yarowsky-propagation-acl2012
Code available at: https://github.com/sfu-natlang/yarowsky